# Pandas - converting datamonth yyyymm to datetime yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, format

I have a dataframe in pandas with some columns with dates in the following format

| dates |
| --- |
| 202001 |
| 202002 |

I want to convert them to the following format

| dates |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-02-01 |

Could anyone assist with converting the date format? Thanks

Comment: have a look at [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and e.g. https://strftime.org/ to get the formatting directive right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need datetimes use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format='%Y%m'`:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `to_datetime` here:

```py
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"] + '01', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

Note that your current text dates are year month only, so I concatenate `01` to the end of each one to form the first of the month, for each date.

Comment: check `errors='ignore'` ;) It working differnet like you think

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].astype(str)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str[:4] + ' ' + df['dates'].str[4:])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       dates
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-02-01
```

Comment: Ya, only not datetimes ;)

Comment: @jezrael Yeah :)